# Trying to understand Backbone.js routing betwen views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller

I am very new to backbone and trying to understand its concepts. I am trying to create a backbone.js application (With underscore templates) where some of the views are protected by a login page and they also have a logout button on them.

The idea is that if a non-logged in user navigates to a specific view, he should see a login page and once he logs in be redirected to the view he originally tried to go to. The code looks like this

`router code`

```
routes: {
    ""                  : "home",
    "authView"             : "authView",
},

login: function(view) {
        if(isUserLoggedIn()) {
            $('#content').html(view.el);
        } else {
            var loginView = new LoginView(view.model)
            $('#content').html(loginView.el);
            app.vent.on("login:success", function(){
                loginView.remove();
                $('#content').html(view.el);
            });
        }
    },

authView: function() {
    this.login(new authView());
}
```

`authView`

```
AuthView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click #logoutbutton": "logout"
  },

  initialize:function () {
    this.render();
  },

  render:function () {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
    return this; 
  },
  logout:function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    logUserOut();
    app.router.navigate("authView", {trigger:true});
  }
});
```

The generic login route protection seems to work however I am not sure if this is the best way to do it (As the view itself is not auth protected, only the route).

My issue is that I am not sure how to handle logout. The idea is that the user is thrown back to the login page and should he login again, he should be routed to the same view he came from when he pressed the logout button.

The current idea is to simply recall the same route so the login function is called however it seems that backbone will not do anything if the navigate function is trying to navigate to the route it's already in. Also calling the view .render() method in this case is not options since it bypasses the authentication code (Which is only on the route).

How does on handle that in backbone? Am I over complicating things? Should the authentication protection be placed in the view itself? I thought of that but couldn't arrive at a solution which did not seem overcomplicated.

Comment: Backbone provides some example with `execute` method http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute

Answer (score 0):

I override router's execute function as follows

```
execute: function (callback, args, routeName) {
    // ..
    if ( /* Check if user is not authenticated */ ) {
        Backbone.history.navigate("logout", {trigger: true});
        return;
    }
    if ( callback ) {
        callback.apply(this, args);
    }
}
//..
// logout route
logout: function () {
    // do the logout logic..
    // ..
    Backbone.history.navigate("login", {trigger: true});
}
```